# Getting screen resolution in Netwide Assembler?

Tags: assembly, nasm, osdev

I'm experimenting with OS development and already wrote a boot sector. I wonder if there is some function (or a way to implement it) for getting screen width & height in graphics mode.

I'm trying to write a basic NASM a program that draws pixels on screen (just for exercise) and somehow drawing pixels diagonally I managed to fill entire screen (I'm using Bochs 2.7). That looks a bit ugly and I wonder if there is some way to get screen resolution so I could fill screen in a nicer way like fill current row, go to next row, repeat?

Comment: If you have written a boot sector seems you don't use UEFI boot etc. In this case you select what screen resolution will be by setting up required video mode.

Comment: You can try to use functions ah=0f and ax=4f03h of video BIOS (int 10h) but likely it will be text mode 80x25.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to *set* the screen resolution, e.g. to a graphic mode instead of text mode?  Or do you mean query the max supported resolution for the monitor + video hardware?

Comment: NASM has basically nothing to do with the question, FYI. NASM is just a way of writing the CPU instructions in text form.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to draw a pixel you need 6 pieces of info:

- the physical address of the video card's frame buffer (and/or the virtual address of wherever you felt like mapping the video card's frame buffer in virtual memory).
- the "bytes per pixel"
- the "bytes per row". Note that there can be unused padding at the "right end" of every row of pixels, so you can not assume "bytes per row = bytes per pixel x pixels per line".
- the number of pixels per row (mostly to prevent "overdraw" - drawing stuff past the right edge of the screen and making a mess)
- the number of rows
- some clue what the format of a pixel is (e.g. if it's RGB or BGR or CMYK or something else, and which bits are used for what, and how many bits are unused/ignored).

An OS/boot loader typically gets this information for all video modes (before it decides which video mode it wants/supports, before it sets a video mode); then stores all the information for later. The information mostly comes from firmware APIs (from VBE for BIOS, or from UGA or GOP for UEFI).

To get the information that you stored yourself it can be as simple as reading the value/s from variable/s (but I'd recommend a nice structure, especially for multi-monitor support).

Comment: I'd imagine YUV is a more plausible pixel format than CMYK, although that was good for a laugh.

Comment: @PeterCordes Theoretically electronic ink display controllers could support CMYK. But i doubt VESA or UEFI does.